# Extracting symbols from a given formula

Tags: prolog, prolog-defaulty

I'm trying to extract symbols from formula. Ex:

```
?- formula((p v q) & (q v r), U).

U = [p, q, v].
```

What I've done so far:

```
simbol_formula([],[]).
simbol_formula(negation X, [X]).
simbol_formula(X or Y, [X,Y]).
simbol_formula(X and Y, [X,Y]).
```

I believe what I did is correct but incomplete. I am stuck. It obviously works for simple formulas but for more complex formulas it does not. I know I have to define something as `simbol_formula(F,U) :-`. Using recursion somehow or break the given formula into "smaller" ones.

Answer (score 1):

The core problem in your case is the use of **defaulty** data structures.

In your representation, you cannot, by *pattern matching alone*, distinguish between:

- a **symbol**
- *other* formulas.

To overcome this shortcoming, I suggest to uniquely mark *symbols* with the (arbitrary) functor `s/1`.

For example, the formula `(p v q) & (q v r)` would be represented as:

> ```
> (s(p) ∨ s(q)) & (s(q) ∨ s(r))
> ```

Then, we can use a **DCG** to *relate* formulas to symbols:

```
symbols(s(X))        --> [X].
symbols(negation(F)) --> symbols(F).
symbols(X ∨ Y)       --> symbols(X), symbols(Y).
symbols(X & Y)       --> symbols(X), symbols(Y).
```

Sample query:

```
?- phrase(symbols((s(p) ∨ s(q)) & (s(q) ∨ s(r))), Ls).
Ls = [p, q, q, r].
```

I leave defining the suitable **operators** as an exercise, so that the above compiles.

The above can also be used to *enumerate* formulas, albeit unfairly:

```
?- phrase(symbols(Formula), Ls).
Formula = s(_G1010),
Ls = [_G1010] ;
Formula = negation(s(_G1012)),
Ls = [_G1012] ;
Formula = negation(negation(s(_G1014))),
Ls = [_G1014] .
```